# Triple integral over region in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integrate over the following region in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$V = \lbrace{ (x, y, z): x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2, 0 <z<1\rbrace}$$

My approach:

$$1=\int_0^1\int_0^{z^2}\int_{-\sqrt{z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2-y^2}} (f) dxdydz$$

Are my bounds correct? In $\mathbb{R}^3$ this set seems to be some sort of solid cylinder (I think).

Comment: I suggest cylindrical coordinates and using the order of integration $dzrdrd\theta$. Notice that your region of integration $S$ is (filled in) region bounded below by the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and above by the plane $z=1$. I always recommend to visualize the region of integration before proceeding to setting up the bounds of the triple integral.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2 \leq z^2$ is an inverted cone with vertex at the origin and cross sections being circles of radius $z$. While I will come to the triple integral, you can easily write the integral as

$ \pi k \displaystyle \int_0^1 z^3 dz$ (this is because the area of cross sections are $\pi z^2$ with radius $z$.

The correct triple  integral should be

$\displaystyle k \int_{0}^1\int_{-z}^{z}\int_{-\sqrt{z^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2-y^2}} z \ dx \ dy \ dz = \frac{k \pi}{4}$

(Plug in $y = 0$ to get the bounds of $x$ which is $\pm z$).

To make it easier to integrate, you can also convert this into cylindrical coordinates using

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta, z$.

Then rewrite the equation of the cone and you see it is $z = r$ for $z \gt 0$.

At $z = 1, r = 1$.

So you can write the integral as

$\displaystyle k \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{r}^{1} z \ r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{k \pi}{4}$

Comment: In fact I would suggest to simply take the area of cross sections in terms of $z$ and integrate over bounds of $z$. Please see the first part of my answer.